# Css styling one weird comma

Tags: css

I have this issue now, here is the html code of some text

```
<div class"no-date">
<a href="example.com" rel="category tag">Food</a>
", "
<a href="example.com" rel="category tag">Travel</a>
", "
<a href="example.com" rel="category tag">Christmas</a>
</div>
```

I managed to change the color of the text (Food, travel, christmas) to a color depending on the rel with this code

```css
div[class*="no-date"] > a[rel*="category"] {
    color: #e8ce25 !important;
}
```

But the commas "," are still black but i want only on this div to make them the same color as the text. Have no idea even how to google search it.

(its a wordpress theme and i can only add css style)

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Since the commas aren't in the category the CSS specification can't apply to them. Remove the reference to the category so taht the color is applying only to the div and the entire content of the div should be the same color...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div[class*="no-date"], div[class*="no-date"] > a[rel*="category"] {
    color: #e8ce25 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="no-date">
  <a href="example.com" rel="category tag">Food</a>
  ", "
  <a href="example.com" rel="category tag">Travel</a>
  ", "
  <a href="example.com" rel="category tag">Christmas</a>
</div>
```

By the way, why don't you use `div.no-date, div.no-date > a[rel*="category"] {`

Comment: Oh... great.. I didn't knew about the 2 div seperated by comma... Do you have any documentation about this? Thanks a lot btw <3

Comment: For what exactly do you need an documentation?

Comment: for the comma between the 2 div[class*="no-date"] i didnt knew about it.

Comment: Well you can declare the same rule for multiple classes at the same time like that. It's basicly a list